# Correct verbiage for setting ranges equal

Tags: excel, vba

what is the correct verbiage making a range of cells equal to another?
I have a variable that gets the last column.

```
Sub Submit()
Worksheets("TRACKER").Activate
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range("LastColumn & 1: LastColumn & 16").Value = Worksheets("INPUTXL").Range("B3:B18")
    Worksheets("INPUT").Activate
End Sub
```

I get the nice method range object error of course, because of that mis-worded line. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to use `Cells` notation.

```
Sub Submit()

Dim LastColumn As Long

With Worksheets("TRACKER")
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(.Cells(1, LastColumn), .Cells(16, LastColumn)).Value = Worksheets("INPUTXL").Range("B3:B18")
End With

Worksheets("INPUT").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range("LastColumn & 1: LastColumn & 16").Value = Worksheets("INPUTXL").Range("B3:B18")
```

should be:

```
Dim LastColumn As String
LastColumn = Chr(64+ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
Range(LastColumn & "1:" & LastColumn & "16").Value = _ 
     Worksheets("INPUTXL").Range("B3:B18").Value
```

Comment: @SJR; fixed - i didn't see that!

Comment: @JMP Side note: Changing column numbers to characters via Chr() functiong would be limited 
to columns from A:Z. 
A simple conversion could be done by: Split((Columns(n).Address(,0)),":")(0) 
where n represents the numeric column value.